# Error while granting permissions to datalake locations via CDK

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, data-lake

In CDK, I am registering a datalake location with the following code:

```
lakeformation.CfnResource(scope, "S3BucketRegistrationResource",
  resource_arn="arn:aws:s3:::my-s3-bucket-here/my_db_folder_here/",
  use_service_linked_role=True
)
```

And also, grant permissions to a principal on that location, via:

```
data_location = lakeformation.CfnPrincipalPermissions.DataLocationResourceProperty(
    catalog_id=Aws.ACCOUNT_ID,
    resource_arn="arn:aws:s3:::my-s3-bucket-here/my_db_folder_here/"
)
cfn_principal_permissions = lakeformation.CfnPrincipalPermissions(scope, "DatalakePrincipalPermissions",
    permissions=["DATA_LOCATION_ACCESS"],
    permissions_with_grant_option=["DATA_LOCATION_ACCESS"],
    principal=lakeformation.CfnPrincipalPermissions.DataLakePrincipalProperty(
        data_lake_principal_identifier=f"arn:aws:iam::my_acct_id_here:user/my_user_here"
    ),
    resource=lakeformation.CfnPrincipalPermissions.ResourceProperty(
        data_location=data_location
    ),
    catalog=Aws.ACCOUNT_ID
)
```

When I try to deploy, the registering data location part goes well (it creates the registration entry)

But the grant permissions part yields this error:

*CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::LakeFormation::PrincipalPermissions | DatalakePrincipalPermissions
6:27:34 PM | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::LakeFormation::PrincipalPermissions | DatalakePrincipalPermissions
Resource handler returned message: "**Resource does not exist or requester is not authorized to access requested permissions.** (Service: LakeFormation, Status Code: 400, Request ID: b29f926b-5ab2-49ec-8bee-42bc8fbc12d8)" (RequestToken: 6cc21ec7-c67a-d4c1-c3f0-3af6b0a7451d, HandlerErrorCode: AccessDenied)
at FullCloudFormationDeployment.monitorDeployment (/usr/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:380:10236)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async deployStack2 (/usr/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:383:145775)
at async /usr/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:383:128776
at async run (/usr/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:383:126782)*

Why would I have permissions problems via CDK only? what would be the best way to troubleshoot this?

When I do the same grant process manualy, directly at the AWS UI console, I have no problems with permissions, or the resource location

When run manually in their UI interface, I am also using the same user that is running the CDK code in my laptop.

Comment: disregard: the issue is that CDK runs on a role that is different from the aws profile that is on your local computer that runs the CDK code. In order to make it work, you need to promote the internal cdk role to a datalake admin temporarily, as indicated here: https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-glue-streaming-etl-with-apache-iceberg/blob/main/cdk_stacks/lakeformation_permissions.py

Answer (score 0):

This is authorization issue. I think the role with which you are trying to  run cdk is not **lakeformation admin**.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).